# primefaces calendar time picker sends null value when it is disabled

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, calendar, datetimepicker

Prime faces calendar time picker sends null value when it is disabled or not selected.
How can i set default value for time picker.

Please share your views.

Comment: Please show some code